# Is there is any better way to export bulk data into excel using C# or SQL Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, excel

I have a search page in my application which can search data based on two dates. The user can also export the data into excel. I am using normal asp.net grid view to display data. In export to excel I am inserting data into excel from sqlserver using OPENROWSET method (This sometime throws linked server null error, did all suggestions given in various technical sites but still sometimes error occurs).

When the user exports one year of data into excel the page takes minimum 20 minutes to export even though the query returns data faster, writing into excel using openrowset taking more time. 1 year data is about 2 million records, Earlier I was using c# code to write data into excel that was also taking more time. The excel file size for one year data goes above 200 mb.

Is there a better way for bulk data excel export?

Comment: "20 lakhs records"? 2,000,000 rows do not fit into one `Excel` sheet.

Comment: `lakhs` is neither an English word nor a programming term. In any case, if you have to export that much data something is wrong - the users should be using the *database* to process data, not export them and work on them themselves. Anyway, in such cases its better to create an Excel sheet with a PowerQuery or PowerPivot connection and have the users retrieve the data themselves

Comment: @AxelRichter depends - with PowerPivot Excel can load much more for processing, aggregations etc. It still can't *display* more rows.

Comment: Nobody is going to look at 2 million rows, even if Excel could display them all.  Just do the aggregation inside the server in a view and set up a data source inside of Excel to access it.

Comment: Thanks all for your valuable replay. I have already told to client it does not make sense with this much of data. But they are asking at least for 6 months that also comes around 1 million records. When they exports excel for 6 months or 1 year the whole application performance affecting.

Comment: You need to consider changing to an offline model.  User makes a request.  Does not wait.  Offline creates the file...emails the user a link to the (zipped?) file that can be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

SSIS is good for exporting large amounts of data.

Comment: True, but treating the question as academic, I answered it.   What the user does with such a large excel file is another problem.

Comment: The OP should probably rethink the use case. More often than not, when users ask for full exports it means that the system can't do what they want so they try to do it themselves. Or that the *department* is too slow to respond. Or that they want to add eg marketing data. Even then, PowerPivot would allow the users to read, match, lookup, mix other data sources to their hearts content. It would also require *less* memory to load that much data in PowerPivot than individual rows

Comment: You're probably right, but until the OP says WHY they want so much data in an Excel file, we'd just be guessing.   Maybe it's for offline portability, in which case .csv would probably be better.

Comment: Which is why "Why?" is the most important question a dev should ask. Exporting that many rows can be more expensive than finding what the goal is and solve it

Comment: When I raised what you going to do with this much of data? they just told we will check performance of the user who puts data from various places. I do not know how they will compare this much of data.

Comment: Shame they won't tell you the performance indicators so you can just bulid the report they actually want.

Answer (score 0):

Have SQL Server create an SSIS package for you and The SSIS package will be much,much faster then code. To do so:

```
1. In SQL Server Management Studio Right Click on the target database and click on Tasks in the pop-up  menu 
2) Select Import Data
3) On Data Source select Microsoft Excel and browse to where the excel spreadsheet will be.
```

Continue with the selections and make sure you save the resulting package.

The package can be run as a SQL Server job or from the command line using the dtexec (a SQL Server util) command..

The SSIS package will process 2000000 rows very quickly (on my machine it reads 10000 rows per second - your results will vary).